# disable button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, button, disable

I have a series of buttons that execute internal logic(no forms not dependant on input), but call the functions asynchronously. I would like to disable the button after one click, and have tried several things on `onclick()` method but keep getting errors.

Code looks something like this:

```
{ this.state.isEthTransferVisible && <button id="button"
                  onClick={() => { parseAddress(this.state.sc);}, this.handleTransferFromEthereum}>Check Balances</button>
}
```

this is the function called from within the `onclick`

```
async handleTransferFromEthereum(){
  await parseAddress(this.state.sc)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
         isEthTransferVisible: !prevState.isEthTransferVisible,
         isGoDeployedVisible: !prevState.isGoDeployedVisible
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another state variable, such as `this.isEthTransferEnabled` (Default true). Change your button to:

```
{ this.state.isEthTransferVisible && <button id="button"
                  disabled={this.state.isEthTransferEnabled}
                  onClick={() => { parseAddress(this.state.sc);}, this.handleTransferFromEthereum}>Check Balances</button>
}
```

And change your handleTransferFromEthereum method:

```
async handleTransferFromEthereum(){
  this.setState({ isEthTransferEnabled: false });
  await parseAddress(this.state.sc)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
         isEthTransferVisible: !prevState.isEthTransferVisible,
         isEthTransferEnabled: true,
         isGoDeployedVisible: !prevState.isGoDeployedVisible
    }));
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something cause its not working. I added   
`constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isEthTransferEnabled: true}
}`

but its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={() => { parseAddress(this.state.sc);}, this.handleTransferFromEthereum}
```

Wrong syntax? It should be:

```
onClick={() => { 
  parseAddress(this.state.sc);
  this.handleTransferFromEthereum();
}}
```

Comment: the code in the question works well, Im asking to disable the button when its clicked. you answer offers no indication on how to do that.